# Proof on $\bigcup A=\varnothing\Rightarrow\forall a\in A, a=\varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is this proof valid?

$\textbf{Claim: }\bigcup A=\varnothing\Rightarrow\forall a\in A, a=\varnothing$

*Proof.*
Let us suppose that there was an $x\in A$ where $x\neq\varnothing$. Since $x\in \bigcup A \Leftrightarrow\exists a \in A,\ x \in a$, there would have to be an $x\in\varnothing$, which is impossible, since $\varnothing=\{\}$, and $\nexists x\in\{\}\ \blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is fine, but it could be stated better. Here’s one possible version:

> Suppose that there is a non-empty $a\in A$. Since $a\ne\varnothing$, there is some $x\in a$. But then by definition $x\in\bigcup A$, and therefore $\bigcup A\ne\varnothing$. Taking the contrapositive, we see that if $\bigcup A=\varnothing$, then $a=\varnothing$ for each $a\in A$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'll accept when the time becomes available.

Comment: @Conor: You’re welcome!